# Relationship between Abstract Algebra and Probability Theory

Tags: soft-question, probability-theory

Is there a relationship between abstract algebra and probability theory? I ask this because of the following laws:

> **Axiom of Countable Additivity:** If $A_1, A_2, \dots \in \mathcal{B}$ (where $\mathcal{B}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra) are pairwise disjoint then $$P \left(\bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty} A_i \right) = \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} P(A_i)$$

and

> **Axiom of Finite Additivity:** $P(A \cup B) = P(A)+P(B)$ for $A,B \in \mathcal{B}$ where $A$ and $B$ are disjoint.

Note that the first implies the second. Also the second implies the first if we assume the axiom of continuity:

> **Axiom of Continuity.** If $A_n \downarrow \emptyset$ then $P(A_n) \to 0$.

So it seems that we can treat these probabilities are homomorphisms. So is there any relationship between abstract algebra and probability theory?

Comment: Whoa! Homomorphisms have to respect the operation for all pairs of arguments, not just the disjoint ones, so I can't see treating probabilities as homomorphisms.

Comment: You can think of the connection between probability and algebra in terms of the sigma algebra of sets from your sample space. Perhaps see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ring_of_sets

Comment: Gerry Myerson is right: $P(A\cup B) = P(A)+P(B)$ if $A$ and $B$ are mutually exclusive, but not generally if they're not.  This doesn't mean there's no connection, but maybe that it's not a really simple one.

Comment: See, for instance, "Partial probability and Kleene Logic:
arxiv-web3.library.cornell.edu/abs/1310.6172